# Query Table Based on Variable Number of Selection Criteria

Tags: sql-server

I need to query a table in SQL Server based on a number of criteria, any of which could be null. Criteria are:

- SaleId
- City
- ZipCode
- County
- JudgementAmountMin
- JudgementAmountMax
- AssessedValueMin
- AssessedValueMax
- Saledatestart
- Saledateend

All of these can be used to filter a selection or just come of them or none of them. I came up with a solution, which broke, and after posting a question asking for help, the responses I received all told me my solution was crap. OK, great, my solution was crap, even though I used a book on stored procedures to guide me and copied most of my solution from the example printed in the text.  So how do I build a solution that isn't crap?

Keep in mind that I am should be considered a fairly new SQL Server practitioner and that I would need more than a two line terse response referring to some general process that can be narrowed down to provide a solution by those who already experienced. I am willing to learn and work at finding a solution,  but ask that the response be more newbie friendly than being told that my solution is not any good and questioning why anyone would do it that way. Maybe because they followed an example in a book and didn't know any better. Examples are very helpful!

Remember everyone has to start somewhere. I am deaf, so going to classes is not an option that has worked for me. I really am trying, I just need some help.

Regards
Tom

Comment: There's usually 2 options, dynamic SQL or option recompile. There's quite a long [post](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog that goes through a lot of options and explains the issues.

Comment: also see:  [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)